# Creating list of objects from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

This takes in a dictionary(words)... note that this is an example, the dictionary can vary in size:

```
{'wandered': [YearCount( year=2005, count=83769 ), YearCount( year=2006, count=87688 ), YearCount( year=2007, count=108634 ), YearCount( year=2008, count=171015 )], 'request': [YearCount( year=2005, count=646179 ), YearCount( year=2006, count=677820 ), YearCount( year=2007, count=697645 ), YearCount( year=2008, count=795265 )], 'airport': [YearCount( year=2007, count=175702 ), YearCount( year=2008, count=173294 )]}
```

And then my function returns A list of WordCount objects in sorted order from least frequent to highest:

```
def wordFrequencies(words):
    count = []   
    for item, val in words.items():
        for i in val:
            wc = createWordCount(str(item), int(i.count))
            count.append(wc)
    newcount = count
    newcount.sort(key = lambda x: x.count)
    print(newcount)
```

Output:

```
[WordCount( word='wandered', count=83769 ), WordCount( word='wandered', count=87688 ), WordCount( word='wandered', count=108634 ), WordCount( word='wandered', count=171015 ), WordCount( word='airport', count=173294 ), WordCount( word='airport', count=175702 ), WordCount( word='request', count=646179 ), WordCount( word='request', count=677820 ), WordCount( word='request', count=697645 ), WordCount( word='request', count=795265 )]
```

But what I need is A list of WordCount objects in decreasing order from most to least frequent that adds the previous count each time to the previous object instead of just adding in a new object,it should look like this:

```
[WordCount( word=’request’, count=2816909 ),
WordCount( word=’wandered’, count=451106 ),
WordCount( word=’airport’, count=348996 )]
```

Comment: Is YearCount a function ?

Comment: YearCount is an object that holds the year and count

Comment: You mean it should be cumulative?

Comment: Yeah I need it cumulative instead of adding new objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def wordFrequencies(words):
    count = []   
    for item, val in words.items():
        c = 0
        for i in val:
            c+=int(i.count)
        wc = createWordCount(str(item), c)
        count.append(wc)
    newcount = count
    newcount.sort(key = lambda x: x.count,reverse=True)
    print(newcount)
```